Cannot find the Material3 Icon in Android Settings/System/Gestures
In the System Settings menu of Android, I want to find the icon of the "Gestures" heading.
I tried to search the Material3 Icon library several times and a Google Picture search did also not yield a desirable result.
Does anyone know, how this icon is known?

I've found the Icon by accident. It's the "App shortcut".

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
